# SilverStripe: Creating form fields statically and via the 'new' keyword

Tags: static, subclass, instantiation, silverstripe

I've been trying to find some info on difference between instantiating form fields through static method and the `new` keyword. Can somebody tell me what are the practical implications, limitations, between `new MyFormField` and `MyFormField::create()` esp. with regards to SilverStripe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `create` factory method would check for overloads (set via `Object::useCustomClass()`) and return an instance of the custom class in that case.

> This method first for strong class overloads (singletons & DB
>   interaction), then custom class overloads. If an overload is found, an
>   instance of this is returned rather than the original class. To
>   overload a class, use Object::useCustomClass()

So using the `create` method rather than instantiating the Object yourself would provide a possibility to overload the used Class without altering the code.

see
 http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Object.html#_useCustomClass
  http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Object.html#_create

Comment: I wonder what the performance hit of `create` is as it in turn uses `Injector`, creating one if there isn't an instance already then `get` has quite a lot of additional code to execute.